# RxJS groupBy, mergeMap, emit each single value from array. Best practice?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am writing here because I am struggling to find a better way to write the following code:

```
this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures').subscribe(fixtures => {
  from(fixtures).pipe(
    filter(fixture => fixture.statusShort === MatchShortStatus.NS),
    groupBy(fixture => fixture.event_date),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
  ).subscribe(next => this.nsFixturesByDate.push(next));

  from(fixtures).pipe(
    filter(fixture => MatchFinished.includes(fixture.statusShort)),
    groupBy(fixture => fixture.event_date.split('T')[0]),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray()))),
  ).subscribe(next => this.ftFixturesByDate.push(next));
});
```

`this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures')` is returning an `Observable<Fixture[]>`.

This code is doing exactly what I want but I don't like subscribing twice.

I have already tried something like that:

```
this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures').pipe(
  concatAll(),
  filter(fixture => fixture.statusShort === MatchShortStatus.NS),
  groupBy(fixture => fixture.event_date),
  mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
).subscribe(next => this.nsFixturesByDate.push(next));

this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures').pipe(
  concatAll(),
  filter(fixture => MatchFinished.includes(fixture.statusShort)),
  groupBy(fixture => fixture.event_date.split('T')[0]),
  mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
).subscribe(next => this.ftFixturesByDate.push(next));
```

But it doesn't work!

Thanks for helping...

---

**UPDATE**

The following code is also working as expected but maybe we can do better:

```
    this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures').pipe(
      map(array => from(array).pipe(
        filter(fixture => fixture.statusShort === MatchShortStatus.NS),
        groupBy(fixture => fixture.event_date),
        mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
      )),
      mergeAll(),
    ).subscribe(next => this.nsFixturesByDate.push(next));

    this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures').pipe(
      map(array => from(array).pipe(
        filter(fixture => MatchFinished.includes(fixture.statusShort)),
        groupBy(fixture => fixture.event_date.split('T')[0]),
        mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
      )),
      mergeAll(),
    ).subscribe(next => this.ftFixturesByDate.push(next));
```

Comment: And what if you remove the `concatAll` from the pipe?

Comment: It emits an array and not single values so the filter, groupBy and mergeMap can't work !

Comment: OK, I think I get it. So, in your first snippet, you're artificially making an observable out of array. No reason you can't do that in the second one: start the pipe with `map(array => from(array))`.

Comment: @mbojko I have answered you in the post above!

Comment: My answer looks more messy and not really solving anything, I'm just deleting it.

Comment: @mbojko so no more ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

slightly better IMO:

```
const createFixtureProcessor = (filterFunc, groupByFunc) => this.store.select<Fixture[]>('fixtures').pipe(
  map(array => from(array).pipe(
    filter(filterFunc),
    groupBy(groupByFunc),
    mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
  )),
  mergeAll(),
);

createFixtureProcessor(
  fixture => fixture.statusShort === MatchShortStatus.NS,
  fixture => fixture.event_date
).subscribe(...);

createFixtureProcessor(
  fixture => MatchFinished.includes(fixture.statusShort),
  fixture => fixture.event_date.split('T')[0]
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I really like your idea of the processor to stay DRY! In your opinion, is the processor itself written in the best possible way ?